# How to remove input text on buttonclick and format output text right in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

forbiddenWords=['for', 'and', 'nor', 'but', 'or', 'yet', 'so', 'not', 'a', 'the', 'an', 'of', 'in', 'to', 'for', 'with', 'on', 'at', 'from', 'by', 'about', 'as']

def new_sentences(sentenceList):
    global newsentences
    newsentences=[]
    for lause in sentenceList:
        import re
        from random import randint
        s6nade_arv=len(lause.split(' '))
        while True:
            asendatava_idx=randint(0,s6nade_arv-1)
            wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  lause).split()
            asendatav_s6na=wordList[asendatava_idx]
            if asendatav_s6na.lower() not in forbiddenWords:
                break
        uus_lause=lause.replace(asendatav_s6na, "______")
        newsentences.append(uus_lause)
    return newsentences

def IntoSentences(paragraph):
    paragraph = paragraph.decode('utf-8').replace(u'\u014c\u0106\u014d','-')
    import nltk.data
    sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    global sentenceList
    sentenceList = sent_detector.tokenize(paragraph.strip())
    return sentenceList

def full_function():
    IntoSentences(text.get(1.0,END))
    new_sentences(sentenceList)
    text.insert(INSERT, newsentences)

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
label = Label( root, textvariable=var)
var.set("Fill in the caps: ")
label.pack()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

button=Button(root, text ="Create text with caps.", command =lambda: full_function())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Everything works the way it has to. The program takes user input as some sentences. When the button is clicked it should output text with caps. But there are two things I want to change. First of all there is letter "u" at the beginning of every sentence, how to remove that? And secondly How to make the program to remove input text from screen, whn it otputs text with caps?

Comment: The u is for unicode, you will just have to put a string call somewhere. Try text.insert(INSERT, str(new sentences))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The u is for unicode, you will just have to put a string call somewhere. Try `text.insert(INSERT, str(new sentences))` at the very end. As far as getting rid of the old sentences I believe the Tkinter way of doing that is just deleting it before inserting. Try adding in `text.delete(1.0, END)` to your main function right before you insert.

Comment: Deleting old text worked. But still cant get rid of those u's.